# find command - how to ignore case in -path option?

Tags: find, options, case-sensitivity

when searching filename or dirname case-insensetively, we can use option `-iname`.

but if I want to ignore case in `-path` option, what should I do?

can I do it with only `find` command, without using `grep`?

Comment: May be a silly question - but did you check whether your system's `find` provides a `-ipath` test?

Comment: even if it doesn't support, you can do `find -path './[Pp][Aa][Tt][Hh]'`

Comment: @steeldriver actually it has this ```-ipath``` option.  

I am using BSD ```find``` on mac. 

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [GNU `find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Full-Name-Patterns.html) then there's the [`-ipath` option](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

If [`locate`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/locate) is available on your system you can also use `locate -i`

See also

- [Case Insensitive search from find command?](https://superuser.com/q/277235/241386)
- [Find path in bash on insensitive manner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11862746/995714)

Comment: BSD ```find``` also has ```-ipath``` option. thanks!

Comment: sfind has also an `-ipath` option.